# 3 level git repositories (local - organisation - remote) possible and how to set up?

Tags: git, gitlab

we develop code for clients and we have our own git repositories on gitlab. So OUR developers will develop code on their local machines and then push to the remote git repository, which is our gitlab.

From there we spin up our own internal pipelines, creating container, running tests, building dev/test environments, etc.

When a feature (or a group of features) are finished, we want to push this from our gitlab to the client's git server as one commit. The client's own developers also develop on the client's repository, so we also need to be able to pull those changes from the client repo to our gitlab repo and then to our developer's local repo's.

At the moment, we keep track of our latest pull in the client's system and our latest push to client's server in our own system and we create patch files for both that we apply both ways. Needless to say this is not very optimal and giving a lot of headaches.

How can we stream line such a setup?

I saw some posts about git/upstreams, but not sure if that is the way to go.

Comment: Are you looking for [mirrors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/)?

Comment: we're not really mirroring since we create our own branches for testing and such that we don't want in the client's repo. We just want the approved code to be pushed along (and keep it in sync with the client's repo)

Comment: Or if you want full control over when sync happens and what is synced you could config some local repo with two remotes: own server and customers. And manually/semi-manually sync needed branches.

Answer (score 0):

You could create local repo connected to both remote servers and manage updates manually/semi-manualy.

```
git clone https://git.local/repo.git
git add git remote add customer https://git.customer.com/repo.git
git pull
git pull customer master
# handle merge issues if any
git push customer master
git push master
```

If could be reasonably sure that conflicts wouldn't happen, you could even automate this process fully and put into your pipeline.